# Identifier Expected error--problem with Razor Syntax

Tags: razormediator

Below is the block of code that I'm having a problem with.

```
<ul class="description-tabs-menu--tabs-nav">
    @foreach(var fields in Component.Fields.product_tabs){
      <li>
        <a href="#@fields.tab_target_name"
        @if(fields.IsFirst){
            class="active"
        }
        >
        @fields.tab_title
        <span class="tab-bg-left"></span>
        <span class="tab-bg-tip"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
    }
</ul>
```

When attempting to save the template in Tridion, I get the following error:

> TemplateCompileException: CS1513: } expected
>
> Line 599 Column 33: Write(fields.tab_target_name);
>
> WriteLiteral("\"\n");
>
> - if(fields.IsFirst){ class="active" }WriteLiteral(" >\n ");
>
> CS1001: Identifier expected
>
> Line 600 Column 22: WriteLiteral("\"\n");
>
> if(fields.IsFirst){ * class="active" }WriteLiteral(" >\n ");

Can someone point to a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Try using the `<text>` wrapper around your statements, in order to help the parser identify them properly.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369540/razor-renderpartial-exception-expected

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be better to write that like this using a terniary operator

```
<a href="#@fields.tab_target_name" @(fields.IsFirst ? "class=\"active\"" : "")>
```

As Mihai points out the parser is struggling to identify what is code and what isn't. This should make it a little easier for it.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer so it can help others.